# Can I install skylight in living room to bring sunshine in the basement?

Tags: basement

Is there away to install sun tube/ skylight. In living room to shin down the basement?

Comment: Possibly -- what do the people in the apartment above yours think about it?

Comment: Light tubes can provide light similar to your question but they take a larger space as the length increases. I don't know if the light gained would be worth the lost space to run the tube.

Comment: Fiber optic skylights might be what you want. I've only heard of one place to get them... so sorry for the product recommends, but here: http://www.wascoskylights.com/product/parans-solar-lighting-system/